# NodePort service does not redirect request to another node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-cluster

So I ve an on prem kubernetes cluster with two nodes. I use flannel as cidr.

The problem occurs when I deploy an app and the pod lands on the worker node and I try to access the service using master node ip and service port. Cluster ip is the same as the master node IP. It does not redirect the request to the worker node. I know the app works because it shows me the result when I curl the worker node IP.

What can I do to debug and solve this problem ? Or NodePort is not the thing I need ?

Comment: check if kube-proxy is running on the master node as it creates the iptable rules to route the request coming on the nodeports.

Comment: Kube proxy is working on both nodes

Comment: just run iptables-save on the master node and check if you see any entry for your master ip and if it get's reference to the pod ip.

Comment: The Service is not in the iptables. How can i make sure it gets created even id the pod is not on the master node

Comment: can you see service in the iptables on the worker node.. and also can you access the app from the worker node ip and nodeport ?

Comment: I can access the app using worker node ip but not the master ip. Service is in the iptables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195119/discussion-between-aman-juneja-and-mightee).

Comment: Can you explain a bit about how and where your Kubernetes cluster is setup and running?

Comment: Its on premises. I solbed this by just uninstalling everything and installing again

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like flannel was not connecting to the network. Instead of debugging, i ran kubeadm reset and deleted all iptables,. Ip links and re init with kubeadm. It did work this time. Dns is also working. Weird